# Download .mp4 from URL using Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

How to download .m4v video from given URL with Laravel? I have a URL for example `rtmp://123456.r.cdnsun.net/_definst_/mp4:123456/h264/123456.m4v` ... Can you recommend me a package for Laravel which could make the process easier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what exactly you're trying to achieve. For example, if you want to just copy file from a remote server, you could use [`copy()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php):

```
$remoteFile = 'rtmp://123456.r.cdnsun.net/_definst_/mp4:123456/h264/123456.m4v';
$localFile = storage_path().'movies';
copy($remoteFile, $localFile);
```

Comment: I'm getting this error `copy(): Unable to find the wrapper &quot;rtmp&quot; - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?` ... Should be somewhere option in php.ini to include rtmp support?

Comment: That's because it's a video stream and not just file. Check out [this package](https://github.com/qwantix/php-rtmp-client) which uses curl.

Answer (score -1):

You can use **file_put_contents** to download video from **URL**

```
$video_name="video_name.mp4";
$video_path=public_path('videos').'/'.$video_name;  // path where you want to store video
file_put_contents($video_path, fopen($file, 'r'));
```